# Как создать файл сопоставления для PlayMarket?

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play

При загрузке в PlayMarket файла .aab требуется загрузить дополнительно два файла: Файл сопоставления ReTrace (в формате txt или map), и Нативные отладочные символы (в формате zip).

С нативными отладочными символами я разобрался, они создаются очень просто при сборке приложения на Unity. А вот как создать этот интересный файл сопоставления ReTrace, я совершенно не понимаю. В Интернетах крупицы информации, которую мой маленький мозг отказывается воспринимать как что-то логическое. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это работает!? Лучше прям подробно! Какую кнопку нажать, где открыть. Иначе, видимо, именно этот момент я никак не разберу

Не кидайте, пожалуйста яйцами и туалетной бумагой, я правда не понимаю )

Comment: Не уверен, но вроде в **play market** есть ограничение на доп.файлы в зависимости от аккаунта

Answer (score 1):

Сам прочитал очень много разных и "крайне полезных" форумов и текстов, в итоге нашел все решения в самом Unity. Оказывается, если поставить в определенных местах галочки, можно получить и Файл сопоставления ReTrace (в формате txt или map), и Нативные отладочные символы (в формате zip). Всем спасибо за внимание )

1. Для того, чтобы создать Нативные отладочные символы (в формате zip), необходимо в открытом окне "Build Setting" в строке Create symbols.zip поставить галочку (или выбрать во всплывающем окошке "Debugging".
2. Чтобы добавить Файл сопоставления ReTrace (в формате txt или map), заходим в "Player Settings...", там находим в самом низу "Publishing Settings", "Project Keystore -> Custom Keystore" ставим галочку, во всплывающем окошке ниже находим нужный файл с расширением .ks или .keystore (можно создать в Android Studio или тут же, нажав на "Keystore Manager... " сразу под "Publishing Settings"). После - вводим пароль от самого кейстора, вводим пароль от Alias, почти в самом низу ставим галочку в строке "Release".

ВУАЛЯ! Вы создали все необходимые файлы для отправки своего приложения в Google PlayMarket!!! Я эту информацию искал после Нового года больше двух недель, и сейчас пару недель потратил. Нигде, наверное, так подробно не описано...

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Это для деобфускации кода. Причем java кода

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=ru#zippy=%2Cjava-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-proguard

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=ru#zippy=%2Cjava-файл-сопоставления-proguard

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/806966)